# Paypal Listener in Google App Script - doPost trigger

Tags: paypal, google-apps-script

I have written a Listener for Paypal in Google script. On receiving data from Paypal, I have set up a timed trigger to run a function after the doPost return. Shortly the trigger runs the function to complete verification with Paypal and complete the tasks actioned through the purchase.

However the timed trigger has been giving me problems. Is there an another way to trigger the verification function after the doPost does its return.

Thank you.

Comment: Would probably be helpful if you gave some example code

Comment: What problems is the time-driven trigger giving you?

Comment: The time trigger does not always run the function. I understand that others have had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinked to do it with batch process:

1. Recive your data from Paypal with your script and appendRow from from the process inside a Spreadsheet.
2. Use a Trigger Event OnChange or OnEdit or Timer Trigger to run another Script to finish the process?

Comment: I already use time triggers within the doPost to run another function to complete the Paypal verification. I wish to move away from time triggers. However by using try / catch for the errors I have minimised the  issues around time triggers.